# Segmentation fault on second call of a function

Tags: c, sockets

I'm doing a bit of socket programming and one of the nodes in the system runs this loop.

```
while(1) {
    read_fd_set = active_fd_set;
    waiting = select(FD_SETSIZE, &read_fd_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (waiting < 0) {
      error("ERROR on select");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++) {
        if (FD_ISSET (i, &read_fd_set)) {
            if (i == sockfd[S_IN]) {
                proccess_packet(sockfd[S_IN], sockfd[R_OUT],
                 buffer, atoi(argv[7]));
            }
            if (i == sockfd[R_IN]) {
                perror("yay");
                proccess_packet(sockfd[R_IN], sockfd[S_OUT],
                 buffer, atoi(argv[7]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the initial sender sends a packet everything works fine, including the first call of "process_packet". But when the receiver sends its acknowledgement the program throws a segmentation fault without even entering "process_packet". So I assume it is the call itself considering the perror still triggers before.

```
void proccess_packet(int sockfd_in, int sockfd_out,
                Packet buffer, int p_trans)
{
    int n;
    bzero(&buffer,BUFLEN);
    n = read(sockfd_in,&buffer,BUFLEN);
    if (n < 0) {
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
    }
    if(buffer.magicno == 0x497E) {
        //if((double)rand()/ (double)((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1) > p_trans) {
        write(sockfd_out,&buffer,sizeof(buffer));
        //}
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
typedef struct {
  int  magicno;
  int  type;
  int  seqno;
  int  dataLen;
  char* data;
} Packet;
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, don't keep us in suspense. What does a `Packet` look like.... ? *Include its `typedef` in your code please.*  It looks like a `struct` passed by value, meaning there is no caller benefit to even providing it as a parameter, since whatever it held, you destroy with that `bzero`.

Comment: when the select() returns an error condition, the code should not continue as though the select was successful

Comment: when read() returns an error condition, the code should not continue as those the read was successful.

Comment: the 'read_fd_set = active_fd_set;' where these two items are instances of a struct.   These structs are multifield items.  therefore this statement will not work correctly.   suggest: 'memcpy( &read_fd_set, &active_fd_set, sizeof read_fd_set);'

Comment: the call to process_packet() can have the buffer parameter remove and let the buffer be a local variable inside the process_packet() function.  the parameter: 'p_trans' is not used within the function process_packet() 1) this will cause the compiler to raise a warning about unused parameter. 2) suggest removing this parameter

Comment: in the call to process_packet() unless 'buffer' is an array, where the name degrades to a pointer (which is not the way it is being used inside the function) it should be passed as '&buffer'  then the calls to bzero() read() and write() need to be modified accordingly

Comment: Did you run this in the debugger? That'll give you a much more accurate view of what is going wrong rather than just us eye balling the code. At a minimum it will tell you exactly which line of code is causing the seg fault.

Comment: @user3629249 What's wrong with `read_fd_set = active_fd_set`?